# Specialize template for a set of values

Tags: c++, templates

I can specialize a template:

```
template <class T> T f(T x){ ... }
template <> int f(T x) { ... }
```

As far as i know, I can not specialize it for a whole set of T? For example for several numerical types, like:

```
template <class T> T f(T x){ ... }
template <> (int, double) f(T x) { ... }
```

The round parantheses (int, double) would then represent a whole set of types.

Comment: T is the return-type of the function.

Comment: You may create overload with `std::enable_if` or use tag dispatching.

Comment: You should use std::enable_if and [type traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) to specify characteristics of the type that you want handled by the partial specialization. Take note that return type without any other mean to resolve overload resolution would cause you throuble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd write a type trait class for convenience (because there isn't one in standard library) to check if a type is the same as one of a list of types:

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct is_any_of : is_any_of<T,Ts...> { };

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct is_any_of<T,T, Ts...> : std::true_type { };

template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_any_of<T,U> : std::false_type { };
```

Now you can use it with [`enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to conditionaly enable the *overload* (*not* specialization):

```
template <class T> T f() { /* ... */ }

// unlike normal functions, function templates can be overloaded on return types!

template<typename T>
std::enable_if<
    is_any_of< T, int, double, float, short, std::complex<double> >::value,
    T
>::type
f() { /* ... */ }
```

This unfortunately means that the call to `f` is ambiguous if `T` is found in the list of types. If you really need two overloads you can fix this by doing the same thing with the other overload, only with the condition of `enable_if` reversed (efectively doing "disable_if").

Comment: @Jarod42 Let's pretend I never wrote that :)

Comment: That's a bit too sophisticated for me at the moment, I will need to read some literature first to even understand what it's doing.

But would it also work, if the template is template <int T>, and now I want to have it for several values? Or if it's a template <my_enum_class T>?

Comment: there is something wrong with this trait https://godbolt.org/z/ejjv1eYnz