# Make Template Function Pointer generic

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I have the following code: https://godbolt.org/z/e31EcTbeb

```
template<PyObject* (*fn)(PyObject*, PyObject*[], Py_ssize_t)>
PyObject* python_fastcall(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    typedef struct
    {
        PyObject_VAR_HEAD
        PyObject *ob_item[1];
    } PyTupleObject;

    return fn(self, reinterpret_cast<PyTupleObject*>(args)->ob_item, PyTuple_Size(args));
}
```

and a macro to call it:

```
using PyCFunction = PyObject* (*)(PyObject*, PyObject*[])
#define PYTHON_FASTCALL(f) (PyCFunction)python_fastcall<f>
```

Finally I have a few functions like:

```
PyObject* foo(PyObject* self, PyObject* args[], Py_ssize_t args_length);
PyObject* bar(PySomeObject* self, PyObject* args[], Py_ssize_t args_length);
PyObject* meh(PyDifferentObject* self, PyObject* args[], Py_ssize_t args_length);
```

and I want to be able to do:

```
PYTHON_FASTCALL(foo)
PYTHON_FASTCALL(bar)
PYTHON_FASTCALL(meh)
```

But I get the errors:

```
error: address of overloaded function 'python_fastcall' does not match required type 'PyObject* (PyObject*, PyObject*)' -> PYTHON_FASTCALL(bar)

error: address of overloaded function 'python_fastcall' does not match required type 'PyObject* (PyObject*, PyObject*)' -> PYTHON_FASTCALL(meh)
```

No error for `foo` as the signature matches of course.

Is there a way to make the function accept such function pointers where only the `FIRST` parameter differs?

I tried something like:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct is_any_of : std::bool_constant<(std::is_same<T, Ts || ...)> { };

template<typename fn>
typename std::enable_if<
    is_any_of<fn, 
            PyObject* (*)(PyObject*, PyObject*[], Py_ssize_t),
            PyObject* (*)(PySomeObject*, PyObject*[], Py_ssize_t),
            PyObject* (*)(PyDifferentObject*, PyObject*[], Py_ssize_t)
    >::value,
    PyObject*
    >::type
python_fastcall(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    return fn(self, args, args_size(args));
}
```

But it doesn't work because `fn` becomes a type instead of a function pointer.
Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: `args` is `PyObject*` but `fn` takes a `PyObject**` as 2nd parameter

Comment: `PyObject*[] args` is also incorrect syntax. https://godbolt.org/z/q3csvcMje. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Fixed the example. I just didn't want to bombard the post with huge functions.
Args is actually a tuple that gets converted to an array.

Comment: you should not bombard the question with huge functions. You should prepare a [mcve]

Comment: `PyObject* foo(PyObject* self, PyObject*[] args, Py_ssize_t args_length);` is still bogus

Comment: It's correct. That's the exact signature from the Python documentation and it compiles just fine.

Comment: not here https://godbolt.org/z/38MfzszvY. Is it perhaps `PyObject* foo(PyObject*, PyObject*[], Py_ssize_t);` ?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/e31EcTbeb I created a minimal example that reproduces the issue if you uncomment the `bar` and `meh` in `Py_Methods`

Updated the post as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... because fn becomes a type ...

Its a type because you declared it to be a type here `template<typename fn>`. You can use a non-type template parameter just like you did before.

Without restricting the template parameter you can do this:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};
struct C : A {};

template <auto f> 
void call(auto* a, int x) {
    f(a,x);
}

void foo(A*,int){}
void bar(B*,int) {}
void moo(C*,int) {}


int main() {
    A* a;
    B* b;
    C* c;
    call<foo>(a,42);
    call<bar>(b,42);
    call<moo>(c,42);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bnenTMe6W)

If you want to restrict the parameter to a function pointer with one of the three signatures you can still use the `auto` template argument and then SFINAE on the `decltype` of it. I also fixed the first arg of `call` to the first arg of the function pointer:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A {};
struct B : A {};
struct C : A {};



void foo(A*,int){}
void bar(B*,int) {}
void moo(C*,int) {}

template<typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct is_any_of : is_any_of<T,Ts...> { };
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct is_any_of<T,T, Ts...> : std::true_type { };
template<typename T, typename U>
struct is_any_of<T,U> : std::false_type { };

template <typename F> struct first_arg;
template <typename R,typename T,typename ...More> struct first_arg<R(*)(T,More...)> {
    using type = T;
};

template <auto f> 
std::enable_if_t<
    is_any_of<decltype(f),decltype(&foo),decltype(&bar),decltype(&moo),void>::value
> call(typename first_arg<decltype(f)>::type a, int x) {
    f(a,x);
}



int main() {
    A* a;
    B* b;
    C* c;
    call<foo>(a,42);
    call<bar>(b,42);
    call<moo>(c,42);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rxoP64WjT)

I didn't get your `is_any_of` to compile, so I used the one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24806731/4117728). It has an issue when the last argument matches, here it can be fixed by using `void` as last argument (`decltype(fn)` cannot be `void`).